# What Is A Plus Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Plus Word™.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Plus Words™ | Not Plus Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ALERTEST | DROWSIEST |
| BULLIEST | DANDIEST |
| CLEANLIEST | GODLINESS |
| COARSEST | CORSAGES |
| CRANKIEST | CRANKSHAFT |
| CREEPIEST | CREEPIER |
| CULTURE | COUNTERCULTURE |
| ECSTASIES | ECSTASY |
| FITLIEST | FITTEST |
| FRESHEST | STALEST |
| HONORING | HONORABLE |
| HUMBLEST | HUMBLED |
| KNOWLEDGED | KNOWLEDGEABLE |
| LEVELEST | LEVELHEADED |
| LIGHTEST | LIGHTHEADED |
| LUCKIEST | LUCKY |
| MATCHLESS | PEERLESS |
| NAPPIEST | HAPPIEST |
| REPUTABLE | DISREPUTABLE |
| SIGHTLY | UNSIGHTLY |
| SLENDERER | SLENDER |
| SPICIEST | MILDEST |
| STANDARDS | STANDARDIZE |
| STATUS | STATIC |
| STRESS | STRESSFUL |
| STYLES | STYLISH |
| TOASTY | WARM |
| UNMATCHABLE | UNMATCHED |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Plus Words™,Not Plus Words™
ALERTEST,DROWSIEST
BULLIEST,DANDIEST
CLEANLIEST,GODLINESS
COARSEST,CORSAGES
CRANKIEST,CRANKSHAFT
CREEPIEST,CREEPIER
CULTURE,COUNTERCULTURE
ECSTASIES,ECSTASY
FITLIEST,FITTEST
FRESHEST,STALEST
HONORING,HONORABLE
HUMBLEST,HUMBLED
KNOWLEDGED,KNOWLEDGEABLE
LEVELEST,LEVELHEADED
LIGHTEST,LIGHTHEADED
LUCKIEST,LUCKY
MATCHLESS,PEERLESS
NAPPIEST,HAPPIEST
REPUTABLE,DISREPUTABLE
SIGHTLY,UNSIGHTLY
SLENDERER,SLENDER
SPICIEST,MILDEST
STANDARDS,STANDARDIZE
STATUS,STATIC
STRESS,STRESSFUL
STYLES,STYLISH
TOASTY,WARM
UNMATCHABLE,UNMATCHED
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Plus Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Plus Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Plus word is a word where

> The value of the letters (A1Z26 - A=1, B=2...Z=26) adds up to 100

Examples:

ALTEREST:

> 1-12-5-18-20-5-19-20 = 1+12+5+18+20+5+19+20 = 100

REPUTABLE:

> 18-5-16-21-20-1-2-12-5 = 18+5+16+21+20+1+2+12+5 = 100

It is called a plus word because

> Plus refers to the addition between each letter value

Or as Rubio originally intended

> The title says 'a plus word' or an A+ word which is 100% (roughly)

Answer (score 5):

Well for at least few:

> SLENDERER -> to numbers
>  19-12-5-14-4-5-18-5-18
>  = 100 total
>  REPUTABLE
>  18-5-16-21-20-1-2-12-5
>  = 100 total
>  tried for 10 and still 100 total, so this rule?

Comment: Sorry beat you to it :)